# Need common factor for List2 elements from List1

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
list1 = [ 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 ,16 ]

list2 = [ 16, 32, 96]

final = [j for i in list2 for j in list1 if i%j==0]

print(final)
```

Ans : [4, 8, 16, 4, 8, 16, 4, 6, 8, 12, 16]

There are two lists
list1 has factors and list2 has numbers,
want to find all the numbers from list1 which divide all the number in a list2

Ans i want : [4 , 8, 16]

As all these numbers can divide numbers from list2

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
list1 = [ 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 ,16 ]

list2 = [ 16, 32, 96]

final = [i for i in list1 if all(j % i == 0 for j in list2)]
print(final)
```

Output:

```
[4, 8, 16]
```